# The intersection of two minimal prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a reduced commutative ring (that is, $A$ has no nontrivial nilpotents) and $P_1$, $P_2$ two minimal prime ideals of $A$. Is it true that the intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is zero?

It seems that this has confused some people so let me be clear: a *minimal prime ideal* is a prime ideal $P$ such that there is no other prime ideal $Q$ strictly contained in $P$. Therefore, in an integral domain the only minimal prime ideal is $(0)$.

I ask this question because of one of the problems in Reid's Book 'Undergraduate Commutative Algebra'.

[image]

Comment: Let $p_1 \in P_1,\, p_2 \in P_2$. Then $p_1\cdot p_2 \in P_1\cap P_2$. Is there any reason to assume $p_1\cdot p_2 = 0$?

Comment: I have said that P1 and P2 are MINIMAL prime ideals.

Comment: Well, so what? A minimal prime ideal still contains elements.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $R = \mathbb{C}[x] / ((x-1)(x-2)(x-3))$. The prime ideals in this ring are (the images under the projection $\mathbb{C}[x] \rightarrow R$ of) $(x-1)$, $(x-2)$ and $(x-3)$. But $(x-1)(x-2) \in (x-1) \cap (x-2)$ and $(x-1)(x-2) \neq 0$.

I'm think, though can't remember proof or reference off the top of my head, that the intersection of *all* the minimal prime ideals must be $0$, but the pairwise intersection of any two doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. This has something to do with the problem in Reid's Book.

Comment: You need a reduced ring at least, since the intersection of *all* prime ideals is $\sqrt{(0)}$.

Comment: Good example: since the polynomial is squarefree, this ring is reduced. The proof that the nilradical of a commutative ring is the intersection of minimal prime ideals appears in most commutative algebra texts, and is pretty easy to establish with a localization argument.

Comment: In fact, by CRT we have that $R\simeq\mathbb C\times\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

> If $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ are finitely many minimal primes such that $\bigcap_{i=0}^n P_i = 0$, then the minimal primes of $R$ are exactly the $P_i$.

To see this, let $Q$ be a minimal prime of $R$ and note that $P_1 \cdots P_n \subseteq \bigcap_{i=0}^n P_i = 0 \subseteq Q$.

So by the definition of a prime ideal, $P_k \subseteq Q$ for some $k$ and by minimality, $Q = P_k$.

$\square$

Thus any ring with an infinite number of minimal prime ideals is such that no finite collection of prime ideals intersects to $0$.

The simplest way to construct such rings is to take an infinite product of fields.

Comment: @MichielVanCouwenberghe The statement is correct and the proof is correct too.  Remember we assumed $Q$ is a prime ideal.  By definition, an ideal $Q$ is prime iff for all ideals $I,J$ it holds that $IJ \subseteq Q$ implies either $I \subseteq Q$  or $J \subseteq Q$ (easily checked to be equivalent to the element-wise definition of a prime ideal).  Your counterexample doesn't make sense because if $Q = 0$ and $Q$ is a minimal prime then obviously $Q$ is the only minimal prime of the ring.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was confused and forgot that $Q$ had to be minimal.